# What's the difference between flush the cache from admin panel and through command?

Tags: admin, cache, command

I have seen that we can flush the Magento cache via admin panel **System**> **Cache Management** and as well as by running the below command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I would like to know what's the difference between them?

Is both are working the same?

Could anyone please help me to understand it?

Comment: Both does the same

Comment: both are the same, admin panel way is usable when you don't have access to cli

Comment: Thanks. I thought that there is a reindex option in admin but though the option is available in admin it only works when we run the reindex command via CLI.